# How to remove the default 'Welcome to Open Atrium' splash images

Tags: drupal, open-atrium

I am currently building an intranet using Open Atrium 2 and have followed their guide on how to remove the branding. I have successfully managed to remove the header logo, footer logo, and image on the log-in page. However I am unsure how to remove the 'Welcome to Open Atrium' branding that is displayed on the main home page before logging in. I have tried copying the template file in to my sub-theme and cleared the cache but nothing has changed.

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to the *General* tab at /admin/structure/pages/edit/pm_existing_pages-user_login. In the general settings for the panel there is a CSS class of "oa-login". Edit the panel and remove that CSS class and that will remove the background image.